# Is EJB a ADO.NET equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, .net, ado.net

I happened to be in a Java project though I am .net developer. Also heard lot about EJB. Is it equivalent to ADO.NET in Java?

Answer (score 3):

ADO.NET is what JDBC is for Java. EJB adds an ORM above that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's far more.
ADO is designed for database access from ASP, which is only a part of what EJB is designed to accomplish. EJB also hosts all your business logic (which in a typical ASP application would be coded into the ASP directly, a practice Java EE strongly discourages).

Answer (score 1):

EJB has to be hosted in application server which provides enterprise services like COM+. So you can realate EJB to COM+, but COM is langauge netutral(can be called from any langauge) whreae Java bean is not langauge neutral outside JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) API is the industry standard for database-independent connectivity between the Java programming language and a wide range of databases  SQL databases and other tabular data sources. It provides methods to query and update data in a database, and is oriented towards relational databases - exactly the same as ADO.NET (for .NET)

Answer (score 0):

ADO.Net is a set of API and engine for caching structured data in memory and able to sync those data into a database e.g. MS SQL. As I know, there are not equivalent API/Engine in Java. The closest to ADO.Net is HSQLDB with in-memory mode, but create table and fields must be done through SQL statements (where ADO.Net provides API for creating its internal datatable, relation and etc.)